# Windows Post to LInux, Stream Interpretation, Special Characters

Tags: php, linux, window

I am having an issue getting linux to properly interpret special characters posted from Windows.  I have tried several things and current am at a loss.

The raw input data looks like:

```
A’béaa  ~ ®©™ ¢ ¼½¾ !@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]|\:;"'<,>.?/
```

But .net post adds odd looking A's - Â

When I post the same thing in PHP I have no problems!

Any help is helpful, thanks.

Comment: What does "posted from windows" mean, and "posted to PHP"? Please clarify.

Comment: Smells like UTF-8 to me.

Comment: This might help: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Post from a .net application through http post to a linux machine running php.  The a's show up when I monitor the posted data from windows posted data.  When I post the the SAME exact data from a linux php machine to the same linux php machine - I do not see the a's in the raw post data.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, I resolved my issue after use UTF-8.